# What does "switching runlevel" mean exactly?

Tags: linux, unix, init, runlevel

What happens when I issue `sudo telinit n` (n being the new runlevel)? Does `init` scans `/etc/inittab` and does exactly the same when system is booted? For example, if I have

`rm:2345:wait:/etc/rc.multi`

in my `inittab`, and I change runlevel from 5 to 3. Does `/etc/rc.multi` get re-executed or is it skipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understand of changing runlevels is that `init` "diffs" the old and new runlevel and starts / kills services whose status will changed.

In the given example, `/etc/rc.multi` would not be re-executed because it's already running.  If you had `rm:45:wait:/etc/rc.multi` in your `/etc/inittab`, and went from runlevel 5 -> 3 -> 5, `/etc/rc.multi` would be killed (-> 3) and then started (-> 5) because it's not set for runlevel 3.

From the [manpage](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_telinit.htm):

> When init is requested to change the runlevel, it sends the warning signal SIGTERM to all processes that are undefined in the new runlevel. It then waits 5 seconds before forcibly terminating these processes via the SIGKILL signal.

`/etc/inittab` is rescanned as you described:

> After it has spawned all of the processes specified, init waits for one of its descendant processes to die, a powerfail signal, or until it is signaled by telinit to change the system's runlevel. When one of the above three conditions occurs, it re-examines the /etc/inittab file. New entries can be added to this file at any time. However, init still waits for one of the above three conditions to occur.

Comment: The manpage said "it sends the warning signal SIGTERM to all processes that are undefined in the new runlevel". What about the children of a process (let's say program `/bin/foo`) specified in `inittab`? My guess is that `init` treats the entire tree spawned by `/bin/foo` as a whole, but the manpage is confusing, and how do I prove my hypothesis?

Comment: @xiaq: It says: "Note that init assumes that all these processes (and their descendants) remain in the same process group which init originally created for them. If any process changes its process group affiliation it will not receive these signals." So as long as the process group stays the same, it should kill those as well.  To test it out, you could create a dummy application which forks a couple times, add it to `inittab` and try changing the runlevel to see if the children die as well.

Comment: I'm sorry but what does "process group" mean?

Comment: @xiaq: As described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group), a process group is basically a way to distribute signals (such as SIGTERM) to a bunch of processes at once.  By default all child processes will be in the group of their parent, and thus the cascading behavior when you send a SIGTERM/SIGKILL to the top-level process.  In this case, this mechanism is how init is able to squash all the child processes of a service without explicitly keeping track of them.

Comment: +1 You might consider listing the `layman` meaning of the runlevels - 1 is single user (`root`), 4 is `XOrg`, and so on.

Comment: @new123456 Sorry but what does "layman meaning" mean? (I'm not a native speaker.) And BTW, 5 is XOrg.

Comment: @xiaq - [Definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/layman). You'll find dictionary.com very helpful for words :) Also, I can tell you're not running Zenwalk - on Zenwalk, 4 *is* XOrg.

Comment: @new123456: @xiaq didn't ask for the runlevel definitions, just the behavior of post-boot runlevel switching, so I don't see the need.  And it looks like he knows them already.

Comment: Seems my original question is now fully answered, so I'll accept this answer. Still, I'm not clear about the control flow of `init` with regard to `inittab`, and need more explanation. I've opened another question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/277309/control-flow-of-systemv-style-init).